# what is the relation between not A and everything but A

Tags: probability, logic, propositional-calculus

I am examining Bayes' Theorem, and wondering about the alternative interpretations of ~A, as being:

- not A, ¬ A
- everything but A, ∀-A

And how this will affect the use of probabilities.

So, this is not so much a question about Bayes' Theorem, and more to do with how this split interpretation effects the numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by $\forall$-A?

Comment: It seems to be that the two situations you describe are not distinguishable. Why do you think they are different?

Answer (score 1):

In probability theory, one usually works with a basic set $\Omega$ (of 'possible continuations' of the world), called the *probability space*, and assigns to each *event* a *subset* of $\Omega$. Most often the 'event' word itself is defined as a (measurable) subset of $\Omega$.

E.g. we toss up a coin, then the event '*heads*' will correspond to the set of those possible continuations of the world in which the coin ended up with heads. This is a subset $H$ of the probability space: an event.

Then, what you called 'all', corresponds to $\Omega$, and the event '*not heads*' corresponds to the subset $\Omega-H$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to interpret.

$\neg A$ is just an assertion about $A$ not being true.

The naïve statement "everything except $A$ is true" is inconsistent and hence (we hope) untrue. For example, it implies that $B='1=0'$ and $C='1\neq 0'$ are both true...

Actually, it doesn't really make any sense as a logical statement at all.

Perhaps you could give a clearer *probabilistic* meaning to your statement.

Answer (score 0):

**second statement doesn't state that the the value for A is false.** It just states that **for all other than A, it's true.**

¬ A tells us that the value of the corresponding proposition is false for A.
 ∀-A means a proposition whose value is true for all variables other than A but you can't say anything about A.

so, these are two entirely different things!